# LINQ query to get the all the datarows based on a distinct column

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-dataset

In **VB.Net** I have below LINQ Query

```
Dim temp = (From r In datatable Select r Order By r.str Descending)
```

But I want it to be unique based on `str` column. I know how to get just the `str column` from the LINQ and mark it as `distinct`. But I want the entire row (all columns) and have the distinct based on `str` column

something like

```
 Dim temp = (From r In datatable Select r Order By r.str Descending).distinct(r.str)
```

If some one can give me answer in C# I will translate it in VB.Net

Sample

datatable

```
col1 col2 str
A    B     X
A1   B1    Y
A2   B2    X
```

output should be

```
col1 col2 str
A     B    X
A1    B1   Y
```

Comment: I think you want to use GroupBy : var results = datatable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("str")).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select only first row from rows with same `str` field value:

```
from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
group r by r.Field<string>("str") into g
orderby g.Key descending
select g.First()
```

Or method syntax

```
datatable.AsEnumerable()
         .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("str"))
         .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
         .Select(g => g.First())
```

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly. Sorry if I did not ask the question properly in the first place

Comment: Yes, and this query gives exactly what you want

Comment: My Bad, I got confused by reading the first line in the answer, I will try this query and will accept the answer accordingly. :)   Thank you sire!

Answer (score 0):

First group by the column you want to be distinct, then select the first of each group. This will give you you all the columns for each distinct value in the specified field.

```
dim results = myDataContext.myTable.GroupBy(Function(f) f.myDistinctField).Select(Function(j) j.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: I have added the sample output of what I want to achieve.